# Can I get hold of the original Geofence location from that Geofence?

Tags: android, geofencing, android-geofence

I'm writing an app using Geofences but I would like a `GeofencingEvent` to return the centre of the triggered `Geofence` (in other words, the latitude and longitude given to the Geofence builder when setting it up, rather than the location that actually 'triggers' the `Geofence`).

I realise I can keep a list of the `Location` I use for each `Geofence` and cross reference, but I'm a perfectionist and that method seems a bit dirty, complicated and overblown.

Looking at the `Geofence` code, I note that the `Geofence.Builder` internally returns a `ParcelableGeofence`. I know that I can cast the `Geofence` returned by `getTriggeringGeofences()` into a `ParcelableGeofence` and see what I believe to be the Geofence latitude and longitude in the `agW` and `agX` properties. This doesn't appear to be documented stuff so I'd rather not be using it in an app as it might change at any time (if the Location list is a bit dirty then this method this is utter filth!).

So my question is.... has anyone else either implemented their own version of the `Geofence` interface or extended the concrete `ParcelableGeofence` in order to achieve something similar and more elegant than my proposed hacks?